# Fixed position broken on Android

Tags: android, html, css

I found lots of threads about this topic but no one of them solved my problem.

I'm developing a website with width-based media queries, in order to give to the pages different styles depending on the device.

In the mobile version I need to use a lot of 'fixed' positioning but it brings a very big problem: in the Android Internet, in the iOs Safari and in many other mobile browsers i do not see the fixed positioned tags.
They are there (when I click in a place where a button should be, I see the shape of the button blinking) but they are invisible.
I used the viewport meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, orientation=portrait" />
```

but it doesn't change anything...

I double checked all the z-index and I debugged all the code (looking for some syntax errors) but I'm not able to fix the problem.

Does anyone know what it could be and how to fix it?
Thanks!

**Edit**

If i scale my laptop browser to a "mobile" size and i watch the website in his mobile version, everything is OK.

Comment: Do you have any live examples ?

Comment: @enguerranws Unfortunately not :-(